# Spring JPA TransactionManager not found

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have what I think is a simple project in which I am using Spring to manage JPA and and EclipseLink for my persistence unit. I'm using JavaFX for my front-end and I have split my project into the client module, common module and server module.  I'm using Maven for my builds.  I have been banging my head against a wall for a few days now trying to figure this out.  I have tried different configurations of persistence units and servlet configurations and nothing seems to work.  And the errors always seem to be very similar: something in the transaction manager configuration or usage is suspect.

All help is greatly appreciated.  I'm new to this Spring JPA space, so excuse me if the problem isn't defined adequately.

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.lamtec</groupId>
<artifactId>NewTrialServer</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>NewTrialServer</name>
<!-- Spring Web MVC -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
        <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <url>http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/</url>
        <id>eclipselink</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lamtec</groupId>
        <artifactId>NewTrialCommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Web MVC -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring data -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JPA -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-cr-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- HSQL DB -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Injection framework -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="NewTrialsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>NewTrials</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.lamtec.newtrial.service.Trial</class>
    <class>com.lamtec.newtrial.service.TrialCtWtCheck</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my servlet:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:data="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.lamtec"/>

<bean name="trialServiceImpl" class="com.lamtec.newtrial.service.TrialServiceImpl"/>

<bean name="/new-trial.service" class="org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter">
    <property name="service" ref="trialServiceImpl"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.lamtec.newtrial.service.TrialService"/>
</bean>

<!-- Database Setup -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="NewTrialsPU" />
</bean>
<data:repositories base-package="com.lamtec.newtrial.service.repository"/>

<!-- Transaction Setup -->
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean> 
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

I have two entity classes, Trial:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.lamtec.newtrial.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "Trial")
public class Trial implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "TRIAL_ID")
private Long trial_Id;
@Column(name = "AUX_ADHESIVE1_WEIGHT")
private String auxAdhesive1Weight;
@Column(name = "AUX_ADHESIVE2_WEIGHT")
private String auxAdhesive2Weight;
@Column(name = "AUX_ADHESIVE_1")
private String auxAdhesive1;
@Column(name = "AUX_ADHESIVE_2")
private String auxAdhesive2;
@Column(name = "CT_WT_RANGE")
private String ctWtRange;
@Column(name = "DRIVE")
private String drive;
@Column(name = "DRIVE_WEIGHT")
private String driveWeight;
@Column(name = "FINISH_WT_ACCEPTABLE_RANGE")
private String finishWtAcceptableRange;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "LAMINATOR")
private String laminator;
@Column(name = "LOWER_ADHESIVE")
private String lowerAdhesive;
@Column(name = "LOWER_ADHESIVE_WEIGHT")
private String lowerAdhesiveWeight;
@Column(name = "LOWER_AUX_WEIGHT")
private String lowerAuxWeight;
@Column(name = "LOWER_AUXILLIARY")
private String lowerAuxilliary;
@Column(name = "LOWER_UNWIND")
private String lowerUnwind;
@Column(name = "LOWER_UNWIND_WEIGHT")
private String lowerUnwindWeight;
@Column(name = "TARGET_CT_WEIGHT")
private String targetCtWeight;
@Column(name = "TARGET_TOTAL_FINISHED_WEIGHT")
private String targetTotalFinishedWeight;
@Column(name = "TRIAL_DATE")
private String trialDate;
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TRIALNO")
private String trialno;
@Lob
@Column(name = "TRIAL_NOTES")
private String trialNotes;
@Column(name = "TRIAL_START_TIME")
private String trialStartTime;
@Column(name = "UPPER_ADHESIVE")
private String upperAdhesive;
@Column(name = "UPPER_ADHESIVE_WEIGHT")
private String upperAdhesiveWeight;
@Column(name = "UPPER_AUX_WEIGHT")
private String upperAuxWeight;
@Column(name = "UPPER_AUXILLIARY")
private String upperAuxilliary;
@Column(name = "UPPER_UNWIND")
private String upperUnwind;
@Column(name = "UPPER_UNWIND_WEIGHT")
private String upperUnwindWeight;
@Column(name = "YARN")
private String yarn;
@Column(name = "YARN_WEIGHT")
private String yarnWeight;
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy="trialId", targetEntity=TrialCtWtCheck.class, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
//    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
private List<TrialCtWtCheck> trialCtWtCheckList;
public List<TrialCtWtCheck> getTrialCtWtCheckList() {
    return trialCtWtCheckList;
}

public void setTrialCtWtCheckList(List<TrialCtWtCheck> trialCtWtCheckList) {
    this.trialCtWtCheckList = trialCtWtCheckList;
}


public Trial() {
    super();
}

public Trial(Trial t) {
   //        this.trial_Id = t.getTrialId();
        this.auxAdhesive1Weight = t.getAuxAdhesive1Weight();
    this.auxAdhesive2Weight = t.getAuxAdhesive2Weight();
    this.auxAdhesive1 = t.getAuxAdhesive1();
    this.auxAdhesive2 = t.getAuxAdhesive2();
    this.ctWtRange = t.getCtWtRange();
    this.drive = t.getDrive();
    this.driveWeight = t.getDriveWeight();
    this.finishWtAcceptableRange = t.getFinishWtAcceptableRange();
    this.laminator = t.getLaminator();
    this.lowerAdhesive = t.getLowerAdhesive();
    this.lowerAdhesiveWeight = t.getLowerAdhesiveWeight();
    this.lowerAuxWeight = t.getLowerAuxWeight();
    this.lowerAuxilliary = t.getLowerAuxilliary();
    this.lowerUnwind = t.getLowerUnwind();
    this.lowerUnwindWeight = t.getLowerUnwindWeight();
    this.targetCtWeight = t.getTargetCtWeight();
    this.targetTotalFinishedWeight = t.targetTotalFinishedWeight;
    this.trialDate = t.getTrialDate();
    this.trialno = t.getTrialno();
    this.trialNotes = t.getTrialNotes();
    this.trialStartTime = t.getTrialStartTime();
    this.upperAdhesive = t.getUpperAdhesive();
    this.upperAdhesiveWeight = t.getUpperAdhesiveWeight();
    this.upperAuxWeight = t.getUpperAuxWeight();
    this.upperAuxilliary = t.getUpperAuxilliary();
    this.upperUnwind = t.getUpperUnwind();
    this.upperUnwindWeight = t.getUpperUnwindWeight();
    this.yarn = t.getYarn();
    this.yarnWeight = t.getYarnWeight();
    this.trialCtWtCheckList = t.getTrialCtWtCheckList();
}

...  and getters and setters....

}
```

And TrialCtWtCheck:

```
package com.lamtec.newtrial.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@Entity
@Table(name = "TrialCtWtCheck")
@XmlRootElement

public class TrialCtWtCheck implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@Column(name = "COAT_WEIGHT")
private String coatWeight;
@Column(name = "FINISHED_MATERIAL_WT")
private String finishedMaterialWt;
@Column(name = "RAW_MATERIAL_TOT")
private String rawMaterialTot;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="TRIAL_ID")
private Trial trialId;
public Trial getTrialId() {
    return trialId;
}

public void setTrialId(Trial trialId) {
    this.trialId = trialId;
}

public TrialCtWtCheck() {
    super();
}

public TrialCtWtCheck(Long id, String coatWeight, String finishedMaterialWt, String rawMaterialTot, Trial trialId) {
    this.id = id;
    this.coatWeight = coatWeight;
    this.finishedMaterialWt = finishedMaterialWt;
    this.rawMaterialTot = rawMaterialTot;
}

public TrialCtWtCheck(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCoatWeight() {
    return coatWeight;
}

public void setCoatWeight(String coatWeight) {
    this.coatWeight = coatWeight;
}

public String getFinishedMaterialWt() {
    return finishedMaterialWt;
}

public void setFinishedMaterialWt(String finishedMaterialWt) {
    this.finishedMaterialWt = finishedMaterialWt;
}

public String getRawMaterialTot() {
    return rawMaterialTot;
}

public void setRawMaterialTot(String rawMaterialTot) {
    this.rawMaterialTot = rawMaterialTot;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof TrialCtWtCheck)) {
        return false;
    }
    TrialCtWtCheck other = (TrialCtWtCheck) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.lamtec.newtrials.entity.TrialCtWtCheck[ id=" + id + " ]";
}

}
```

A repository file which looks like this:

```
package com.lamtec.newtrial.service.repository;

import com.lamtec.newtrial.service.Trial;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;


public interface TrialRepository extends CrudRepository<Trial, Long> {

}
```

And my service:

```
package com.lamtec.newtrial.service;

import com.lamtec.newtrial.service.repository.TrialRepository;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Service
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class TrialServiceImpl implements TrialService {
  @Inject private TrialRepository trialRepository;

  @Override
  public void addTrial(Trial trial) {
      trialRepository.save(trial);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public List<Trial> listTrials() {
      return (List<Trial>)trialRepository.findAll();
  }
  @Override
  public Trial findTrial(Long Id) {
      return trialRepository.findOne(Id);
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly=false)
  public void updateTrial(Trial trial) {
      trialRepository.save(trial);
  }

}
```

The war file builds and deploys successfully on a GlassFish 3.1.2.2 server.  My development environment is NetBeans 7.2.

When I run my client against the service, I get the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not deserialize result from HTTP invoker remote service [http://localhost:8080/NewTrialServer/new-trial.service]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:145)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy7.listTrials(Unknown Source)
at com.lamtec.newtrialclient.app.TrialsUIPresenter$1.call(TrialsUIPresenter.java:540)
at com.lamtec.newtrialclient.app.TrialsUIPresenter$1.call(TrialsUIPresenter.java:536)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1229)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:622)
at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:79)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doReadRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:290)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.readRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:241)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:143)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:136)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142)
... 9 more
```

One thing that I do not see in the stack trace, that I do see in the wire traffic between the client and the server is this:

```
    4317 [Thread-4] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content  - << "Exception Description: Cannot use an EntityTransaction while using JTA."
```

Here is the new stack trace:

```
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteAccessException: Could not deserialize result from HTTP invoker remote service [http://localhost:8080/NewTrialServer/new-trial.service]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.convertHttpInvokerAccessException(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:208)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:145)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy7.listTrials(Unknown Source)
at com.lamtec.newtrialclient.app.TrialsUIPresenter$1.call(TrialsUIPresenter.java:540)
at com.lamtec.newtrialclient.app.TrialsUIPresenter$1.call(TrialsUIPresenter.java:536)
at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1229)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:622)
at org.springframework.core.ConfigurableObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ConfigurableObjectInputStream.java:79)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1593)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1750)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1964)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1888)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doReadRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:290)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.readRemoteInvocationResult(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:241)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.doExecuteRequest(CommonsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:143)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.executeRequest(AbstractHttpInvokerRequestExecutor.java:136)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:192)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.executeRequest(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:174)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:142)
... 9 more
```

And in the message traffic between the server and the IDE (where I am starting the client) is:

```
"Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException
```

It seems there is error creating the transaction. It might be due to configuration error in the `persistance.xml` or glassfish configuration file.

```
<persistence-unit name="NewTrialsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
```

`EntityManagerFactory` fails to locate the transaction from JNDI. I have not used glassfish that much. But this should be the clue to find the actual problem. There should be some way to verify whether JNDI resource is created in glassfish or not and use that accordingly.

**EDIT**

For quick solution, consider using `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"` and providing relevant `database connection`, `username` & `password` information for the database should help.

Comment: Okay - nice catch Kowser, but it didn't fix it completely, I just get a new problem.  I still get the same cause: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException`  but now I have this in the communication: `Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction`.  I still think there is a config issue, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: @kpenrose probably you can add new error log with the question.

Comment: Just changing transaction-type to RESOURCE_LOCAL causes deployment problem: `SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : The persistence-context-ref-name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean/entityManager] in module [com.lamtec_NewTrialServer_war_1.0] resolves to a persistence unit called [NewTrials] which is of type RESOURCE_LOCAL. Only persistence units with transaction type JTA can be used as a container managed entity manager. Please verify your application.`

Comment: I am afraid, can't help further. Your configuration seems fine. Just go back to `JTA` as earlier. And add the error log with the question. Lets see if that is helpful.

Comment: one more question? is `eclipselink` jars are provided with `glassfish`?

Comment: Added new stack trace to question after resolving mismatch in PU names.  Also, the eclipselink libs are dependencies that and are installed in the glassfish distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a mismatch in transaction types, probably due to the configuration. I think you are using a combination of JTA and Entity based transactions. This whole area gets  a bit messy but I think unless you are querying across a couple of databases, etc, then you can leave JTA out of it and just use simple Entity based transaction management (basically standard database level transactions).

I don't know much about EclipseLink but try using a persistence.xml that uses RESOURCE_LOCAL. Maybe something like this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html#example_persistenceunit

If you really want to use full JTA then you probably can leave your persistence.xml as is and change the configuration of the EntityManager to use JtaTransactionManager. You'll have to google for more details on the web for this.

As a side note the 'ClassNotFoundException' is a bit misleading. This is only what the client throws when it tries to deserialize the real exception from the server. The real exception is the CannotCreateTransactionException, and this gets sent down the wire to your client, but the client does not have this JAR on its classpath so it can't deserialize it and then you see the ClassNotFoundException.

In a standard setup I think you will see the real exception in your server log. If not you could add a try-catch around the body of your server method, catch all and log it (or wrap an aspect around your service classes that does this magically).

Alternatively you could just add the spring persistence and hibernate jars to your client's classpath (by adding them to the POM). This adds bloat to your client but will allow the client to deserialize the exception and then log the full stack trace, etc.

Hope that helps, 
zonski

Comment: Zonski - Success at last.  The problem had more to do with the GlassFish deploy than anything else.  I stuck with JTA, and stuck with the jndi lookup of the entity manager.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As per Exception it seems like your configuration in `perrsistence.xml` and `Application-context.xml` is not compatible for JTA transaction. You can see below configuration where I have used JpaTransaction manager for transaction and data source in JBoss AS server.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/testDS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="restUnit" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceUnitManager">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
                <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>



    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <context:spring-configured />
```

Comment: Also check the compatibility of .jar you have added.